# Is it possible to apply different locks on a same resource

Tags: c#, locking, critical-section

I have a scenario where I need to apply different locks on a section of code. Let's say I have n number of servers and for each server I am calling a method that writes some json to a file.

Problem statement:

For now I only have a single server, that calls a method `A()` which converts some string lines to json and then to file (on each call, goes a string line), the problem arises when sometimes, the method `A()` writes the lines multiple times, i.e. it sends two lines to the method:

Possible Solution (maybe):

I was thinking of apply n number of locks on method `A()` but then it would wait for server A to finish writing before server B gets a chance to write a file.

Comment: What about `ReaderWriteLock/ReaderWriteLockSlim` for this purpose?

Comment: just use **lock** on the code you need to be secured. If any stream locked some code another stream has to wait until the lock releases and then another stream have access to the code and writes.

Comment: Are you saying that there is a single resource, but different instances of an application running on different servers might try to update it, and you need to make sure that only one server at a time does so? If that's the case a `lock` wouldn't help because a `lock` isn't "shared" between the same app running on different servers. In that scenario one option is a table in a database which is used to keep track of whether a resource is locked.

Comment: @ScottHannen Wouldn't a lock shared among a servers prevent from overlapping from those of different locks?

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to create a lock that is shared among servers. A `lock` statement wouldn't help. One server doesn't "know" about the lock on another server. The database solution works if you know that you're only going to have a single instance of the database. It wouldn't scale well. If possible a better solution is to make your application more tolerant of multiple processes attempting to make the same update. For example, instead of updating the resource could they send messages to a queue, and something else reads the queue and does the update?